# Determine if agent inside area of GIS shapefile

Tags: gis, anylogic, shapefile

With GIS map, we can import shapefiles such as points, lines, and polygons. When import polygons, I want to know if an agent is inside the area of polygons or not.

I expected there are functions for shapefile markup such as onEnter() and onExit() to detect events when an agent entering or leaving the area. But I don't find such functions.
Alternatively, I tried to run timed event to check current coordinates of agent. But the shapefile markup doesn't have function contains() which rectangular nodes have. I can't find API to get coordinates of the shapefile polygons neither.